# A confusion with power ratio jargon used in antenna directivity (dBi/dBd)

Tags: radio, decibel

Below is an excerpt from a book:

> Two common terms you'll hear in specifying the gain of an antenna are dBi and dBd. These terms are defined as dB of gain referenced to an Isotrope (dBi) and dB of gain referenced to a dipole (dBd). A dipole has 2.1 dBi of gain, but 0 dBd of gain. It is critical to know which reference the antenna manufacturer uses, because it will have an effect on the path loss and power calculations we will discuss later.
>
> [image: Original excerpt screenshot]

I don't get how dBd and dBi is related with the ratio of 2.1.
Can these units and 2.1 ratio be explained in an easier or pictorial manner?

Comment: By the way, dBd is really not common, at least in my experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An isotropic antenna would radiate equally well (or be equally sensitive) in all directions.

A dipole antenna is directional, radiating little or no power off the ends of the element, instead directing the power at right angles to the antenna element - this results in about 2 dB more power in the favoured direction than the isotropic antenna would provide.

Comment: Is 2dB found experimentally?  Is that due to the antenna pattern?

Comment: The 2dB gain is due to the antenna pattern.  I don't think the gain can be determined by comparison with an isotropic antenna, as I think they are mythical devices - you can't build one.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenna_gain#Gain_in_decibels) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole_antenna#Half-wave_dipole) for more information / derivation.